# Trouble lining up form elements using a label width

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I'm trying to vertically align all my input elements using a fixed width on my labels, but not getting the result I'm expecting.

```
    label {
    width: 75px;
    }
```

Here is a Fiddle I've created with an example: 


http://jsfiddle.net/xRmHj/


Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label {
   width: 75px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xRmHj/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

`display:inline-block;`

on your labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/xRmHj/1/